# How to transfer a vector from upper triangular matrix to the original symmetric matrix?

Tags: julia

I have a very large symmetric matrix called `M`. The size of the matrix `M` is 1000000 * 1000000. Let `M[i,j]` denote the element at `i`th row and `j`th column of matrix `M`. The upper triangular part of the symmetric matrix `M` was saved as a vector called `V`. `V = [M[1,1], M[1,2], M[2,2], M[1,3], M[2,3], M[3,3], M[1,4], M[2,4], M[3,4], M[4,4] ,..., M[1000000, 1000000]]`. I had three questions.

(1) How can I convert `V` to `M` efficiently?

(2) How can I convert `V` to the upper triangular part of the symmetric matrix `M` efficiently?
I mean convert `V` to another matrix `W`. The upper triangular part of `W` is the same as `M` while the other elements in `W` is 0.

(3) How can I convert `V` to the lower triangular part of the symmetric matrix `M` efficiently?
I mean convert `V` to another matrix `Q`. The lower triangular part of `Q` is the same as `M` while the other elements in `Q` is 0.

Comment: If the data are `Float64` then the size of the vector `V` is 4TB, and the matrix `M` will be 8TB. Is this really correct? Then you can hardly keep the whole thing in memory at once. So is this a question about out-of-memory data handling?

Comment: What if the size of matrix M is 100000 * 100000. Thank you!

Comment: Well, in that case the arrays will be 40 and 80GB,  respectively. Much smaller, but still too big to be held in the memory of most computers. But, do you care about the exact size? Are you interested in out-of-memory calculations, or are you assuming it should fit in memory?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the most efficient way to create `M` is to have a custom type that is `<:AbstractMatrix`. This should be almost zero overhead and use no extra memory.

The type would be something like:

```
struct MyMatrix{S, T<:AbstractVector{S}} <: AbstractMatrix{S}
    v::T
end
```

(I am omitting a constructor which should check if length of `v` matches the "half" of some square matrix)

Then you should define the appropriate methods for your type. Their list is given [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array-1) in the Julia manual (and depending on the exact type of a matrix you want they should be implemented differently). In that section there is an example how such an object can be implemented.